# Build data from subsequent rows

Tags: mysql

I'm not exactly sure what terminology to use to ask the question, so part of this is helping me to understand the terminology to use, but another part is identifying the solution. My apologies in advance if this was already answered elsewhere.

I have data that looks like the following:

```
date        symbol  strike  option_expiration   open    high
8/5/19      IWM     100     9/20/19         49.5    49.57   
8/6/19      IWM     100     9/20/19         49.56   49.75   
8/7/19      IWM     100     9/20/19         49.58   49.99   
8/12/19     IWM     100     9/20/19         48.82   50.01   
8/14/19     IWM     100     9/20/19         47.92   48.92   
8/15/19     IWM     100     9/20/19         45.93   45.93   
8/16/19     IWM     100     9/20/19         44.77   45.01   
8/29/19     IWM     100     10/18/19            0       0
```

On one date, I want to add to a row
a) next (day 2) day's open
b) day 2's high
c) day 3's high
d) day 4's high
e) day 5's high

I would like it to look like this

```
date        symbol  strike  option_expiration   open    high        open next       high1   high2   high3   high4
8/5/19      IWM     100     9/20/19         49.5    49.57   49.56       49.75   49.99   50.01   48.92
8/6/19      IWM     100     9/20/19         49.56   49.75   49.58       49.99   50.01   48.92   45.93
8/7/19      IWM     100     9/20/19         49.58   49.99   48.82       50.01   48.92   45.93   45.01   
8/12/19     IWM     100     9/20/19         48.82   50.01   47.92       48.92   45.93   45.01   -1  
8/14/19     IWM     100     9/20/19         47.92   48.92   45.93       45.93   45.01   -1      -1
8/15/19     IWM     100     9/20/19         45.93   45.93   44.77       45.01   -1  -1  -1      -1`
8/16/19     IWM     100     9/20/19         44.77   45.01   -1          -1      -1      -1      -1`
8/29/19     IWM     100     10/18/19            0       0
```

for the unique set of strike, option expiration. (ie if the strike or option_expiration changes, start over - do not use the data from the next unique set of strike + option expiration when completing the fields.

So a) what is it that I'm asking to do (so I learn the terminology) and 
b) how might I go about this?

Thanks in advance

Mary

Comment: please, work in the redaction again, is difficult to read lists in a single line

Comment: Do you want insert datas ? Or extract , read (it's called select) datas for display action ?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I'm looking for inserts if possible.

Comment: I've edited the request. Is that what you are asking for?